# Any Data Annotations tutorials that use EF Database-First approach to explain the subject?

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations, ef-database-first

All tutorials on Data Annotation attributes I've found explain the subject using either Asp.Net or EF Code-First examples. I don't know either of the two, so do you know of any tutorials that would explain the subject using EF Database-First approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that's for ASP.NET Web Forms with EF Database First:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-8

This is the last installment in an 8-part tutorial series.